# Averages in Two Time Periods

Tags: stata

I am using a datasheet with about 87 countries for the years 1985 until 2004. One of my variables is Real GDP per capita. My intention is to create a new variable based on the previous, but with only 2 observations per country -- showing the average for 2 time periods.

So for 1985 I would want the average GDP for the time period 1985 - 1994, and for 1995 the average GDP for 1995 - 2004.

Comment: SO is for professional and enthusiast programmers and almost always you're expected to show code that you have tried. Otherwise, how do I add 2 + 2 in MS Excel would be on-topic here. In this case, it's possible to suggest code from your description, but future questions need to show more effort to get more respect. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the standard here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no data example, no specification of variable names and no code attempt here. But schematically

```
 gen period = year < 1995 
 egen mean = mean(GDPpc), by(country period)
```

could be a start, or even a finish, depending on exactly what you want. If you want to be able to compare periods directly, then something like

```
 egen mean1 = mean(GDPpc / (year < 1995)), by(country) 
 egen mean2 = mean(GDPpc / (year > 1994)), by(country) 

 tabdisp country period, c(mean) format(%2.0f) 
 tabdisp country, c(mean1 mean2) format(%2.0f)
```

will put variables side by side. See also the `tag()` function of `egen`.

Warning: None of this code was tested.

Comment: Thank you so much, the command is exactly what I was looking for.